# blanking a char variable in c

Tags: c, variables

I have declared a char variable ope in function main.
i took the input through getchar function and stored in ope.
Now i want to blank the variable so i will be able to store some other in ope.
Can anybody show me how to do it??
I just want to continuously store the input in ope variable. If it's possible through some other way, kindly guide me. I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the `getchar()` function same way you used it first time.

Here is sample code from the [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char c;
  puts ("Enter text. Include a dot ('.') in a sentence to exit:");
  do {
    c=getchar();
    putchar (c);
  } while (c != '.');
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to blank it, just do getchar() once again.
Eventualy set it to  or "0 char"

```
c = '\0'; or c = 0;
```